# How to read from File into 2d char Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to read from a txt which looks like this:

```
12  
12  
WWWWWWWWWWWW   
W3000000000W  
W0000000000W  
W0000000000W   
W0000000000W  
W0000000000W  
W0000000040W  
W0000000000W  
W0000000000W  
W0000000000W  
W0000000000W  
WWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Into a `String[][]`;

The first 2 lines are the size of the `String[][]`.
This is the code which says

> **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1** at *map[i][j] = temp[j].toString();*

```
public String[][] read() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/College/Java Eclipse/Map.txt"));   
    String line = " ";


    int columnCount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int rowCount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 

    String[] temp;
    String[][] map = new String[rowCount][columnCount];

    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){ 
        temp = line.split("\\s+"); 

        for(int i = 0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<columnCount; j++) {    
                map[i][j] = temp[j].toString();
            }
        }

    }
    br.close();
    return map;

}
```

What is wrong i can't figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **regex** `line.split("\\s+")` is returning a single `String` and you are looping like it is returning an array (in your case) of 12 elements; and anyway you are replacing all your values again and again because you are reading outside the first `for` loop.

Try something like this instead:

```
public static String[][] read() throws IOException {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/College/Java Eclipse/Map.txt"));
  int columnCount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  int rowCount = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  String[][] map = new String[rowCount][columnCount];

  for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    String line = br.readLine();

    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      map[i][j] = String.valueOf(line.charAt(j));
    }
  }
  br.close();
  //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(map));
  return map;
}
```

Comment: @Tux, check the working source code that I just posted